# Android: How to retrieve Activity parent from a fragment inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

From my fragment, inside a **ViewPager**, I want to get the parent Activity:

Method in my Fragment:

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
    if (visible) {
       Activity aa = getActivity(); >>> It's always NULL !!
       aa.findViewById(R.id.my_special_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

The layout of this Activity:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/main_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

 ....

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 ....

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/my_special_button"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:background="@color/background"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to override the OnAttach method in your fragment and save the Activity instance to a local variable inside your Fragment.

Comment: This will appear to work at first. However, if you use the same fragment in multiple activities, it only attaches to them the the first time it opens in that activity. Then, when you go back to an activity that held this fragment previously, very likely you'll be left with the info from the last activity... which is no longer the one you're in. For me, I've found getActivity() in onResume is reliable.

Comment: Awesome suggestion and this is correct Thanks Anders8